# Dynamically loaded Tree Menu using JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Accordian menu for navigating thru an external API (folder structure)

I am attempting to recreate the folder structure dynamically, as the user navigates.

The problem I am having currently, is that: as folders and subfolders are loaded, they lose (or never receive) the inbuilt jqueryui click handling (for un/folding)

```
I wish to save myself having to write my own accordian click handlers
```

but sadly, the structure of the (often nested) accordians is dynamically loaded and doesn't get any handlers assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

After browsing SO and randomly clicking on unrelated 'similar questions' I was able to find a most excellent solution - http://www.jstree.com/
this neat little jQuery plugin addresses *every* requirement I had for my folders navigation menu, and more!

Allow me to post their front page blurb:

*jsTree is jquery plugin, that provides interactive trees. It is absolutely free, open source and distributed under the MIT license. jsTree is easily extendable, themable and configurable, it supports HTML & JSON data sources and AJAX loading.*

jsTree functions properly in either box-model (content-box or border-box), can be loaded as an AMD module, and has a built in mobile theme for responsive design, that can easily be customized. It uses jQuery's event system, so binding callbacks on various events in the tree is familiar and easy.

Just a few of the features worth noting:

```
drag & drop support
keyboard navigation
inline edit, create and delete
tri-state checkboxes
fuzzy searching
customizable node types
```

All modern browsers are supported, as well as IE8

Comment: I've learned so much in the past 4 years - global handlers would have worked here great.